# Retrieving large number of Data from realtime database in correct arrange

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my database, i have large number of items and it is impossible to retrive all this items at one time

For example i have **Users list ** which contain 2 thousands users

Like that:

Users:

```
1-
    email:"user1@gmail.com"
2-
    email:"users2@gmail.com"
3-
    email:"user3@gmail.com"
4- 
    email:"user4@gmail.com"
5-
    email:"user5@gmail.com"
6-
    email:"user6@gmail.com"

*more users*...

2000:
    email:"user2000@gmail.com"
```

in my app, i want to retrieve last 20 then another last 20 then another 20 and so on...

When i work with `limit_to_last(10)`
then use `mylist.add(0 , users)`

it retrieve last 10 item in correct arrangment (descending manner),  and items appears in list from last item then before one then before like that

```
2000
1999
1998
1997
1996
1995
1994
1993
1992
1991
1990
```

And this arrangment is what i want.

My problem begins when i want to retrieve more items...
I know how to retrieve more but I don't know how to put them in correct arrangment
When i load more items it appear unarranged like that

```
2000
1999
1998
1997
1996
1995
1994
1993
1992
1991
1981
1982
1983
1984
1985
1986
1987
1988
1989
1990
```

Which mean first loaded items arranged in descending manner but second loaded items arranged in ascending manner which i don't want.

**How to make all items to be arranged in the same way (desending way)**

Can anyone help, please.

Comment: 2000 is nothing. Better retrieve them at once.

Comment: Right now ,  it is no thing,  but in future,  it may reach 50k or more... I want to know a helpful way to use in retrieving data with correct arrangment

Comment: Please edit your question to show the minimal, **complete** code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem. Without that it'll be hard to say where you're going wrong. I also recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If you manage to store some incremental value (negative) in every user's node then you maybe able to sort them in descending order and paginate the results. For example, let's take this data:

```
1-
    email:"user1@gmail.com"
    userInt: -1
2-
    email:"users2@gmail.com"
    userInt: -2
3-
    email:"user3@gmail.com"
    userInt: -3
4- 
    email:"user4@gmail.com"
    userInt: -4
```

Do note that you'll have to make sure the magnitude of this value is increasing always and should not be same for each user.

After that you can use your query with `orderByChild("userInt")` and `limitToFirst(2)` to get newest 2 users.
For the subsequent queries i.e. you need to get next 2 latest users, you can add `startAfter('lastUserInt')` where `lastUserInt` will be -3 in this case.
As the numbers are negative and Firebase results as ascending latest users will be fetched first.

```java
Query latestUsers = databaseReference.child("Users")
        .orderByChild("userInt")
        .startAfter(-3) // lastUserInt
        .limitToLast(2)
```